# Leaflet + noWrap option not working in above 1.x version

Tags: javascript, leaflet, world-map

I am working in leaflet map chart.
I tried to implement the nowrap option but its not working. please anyone suggest to solve this problem.

I attached my code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    worldCopyJump: true,
    inertia: false
}).setView([10.8, -140.7], 2);

//  OSM tiles
//L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
     maxZoom: 18,
     continuousWorld: false,
     noWrap: true
}).addTo(map);

var marker = L.marker([-29.5, 143]).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup('-29.5, 143');
```

**Important**

When i am using this theme "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" its working but when i tried to use dark theme not working. same code working in  0.x version.

http://jsfiddle.net/rajinikumarr/JKFgD/46

Attachment: [image]

Excepting output: The map should not repeat at any resolution.

Comment: Reproduced with current Leaflet master: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/run/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Looks like the bug is also present with OSM tiles, but not visible because OSM does not serve tiles outside the main world, whereas CartoCDN does for positive X (but not negative)

Comment: You should probably report it on Leaflet bug tracker: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues

Comment: Thanks  for your reply.  Its possible to resolve this now ?

Comment: Its possible to resolve using this theme - http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png   ??\

Comment: There is very probably a way to make up a hacky workaround indeed. You could try to catch tile requests (maybe at URL generation) and abort if outside the main world. Or you could simply hide the adjacent worlds with a big polygon with a hole for the main one…

Comment: Leaflet is behaving as expected, so this is no bug. I think this is a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what is @RSKMR trying to achieve by using `noWrap` in the first place? Display just one tile at z0?

Comment: I am trying to hide the map are repeating. so big resolution(eg-4000px) its repeating. I need to hide the repeating map.

Comment: Have any option to display z0 (for all resolutions) ?

Comment: @IvanSanchez - I attached teh image. pls check it.I need to remove repeated map for all resolutions.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Indeed new behaviour of `noWrap` option (i.e. request tiles outside main world) is closer to its name. I guess OP was especially confused since behaviour changed compared to Leaflet 0.7. [`bounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#gridlayer-bounds) (combined with `noWrap`) is the perfect answer indeed. http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/can/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to remove repeated map for all resolutions.

Use the [`bounds`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.2.html#gridlayer-bounds) option of the `TileLayer`.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. I used these options ie) -continuousWorld: false,
 -noWrap: true, -bounds: [[-90, -180],[90, 180]]

Comment: I have one more question - when map is repeated that time can we show the markers in all repeating maps? Now I am using "worldCopyJump" option to move the marker. but i am expecting to show the markers in all repeating maps. Have any options for that ?